# Scraping Kickstarter but run into HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On the page, there are more than `53,000` projects in total (I'm trying to scrape all the game projects). However, it ran to page `200 (scraped total 2400 games)` and ran into this `error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found -> URL not found`. I tried to increase time.sleep but it didn't work. Is there any way to fix this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use a User-Agent header and look after all the other headers that are supposed to be sent in a normal request to that website.
The timing is good but it will automatically know that you are botting as you have not set a user-agent as  a normal browser.
And I advice you to use the requests lib from python:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/
It holds much more functions and gets updated much more.

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but it didn't work, the URL page stop at page 201. I feel like it's how kickstarter set up their URL. `kickstarter_url = \
'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=12&woe_id=0&sort=magic&seed=2664694&page={}'` Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: `import requests
import random
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

Comment: is there any way I can send you my code privately? somehow stackoverflow doesn't let me edit the post